# How to implement push notification in hybrid app simply?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app

[Tutorial: Implement Push Notifications in your PhoneGap Application](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/)

I found this. It works but I want to push to all installed user. Is there a existing backend template to implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a database with **Registered id** in web server and send push notification to all the **Registered id** in the database from the web server.

The link you posted uses Javascript to send push notification, whereas you have to use PHP or anyother server script to send push notification.